# the for loop is too fast for reading the POST requests? PHP - Array

Tags: php

I've been through a problem reading the POST requests. The main idea is when I press a button, jQuery creates a new div with same rows but with changed name and id.

Example first line:

```
<input type="text" name="pro_name_0"  id="pro_name_0"  placeholder="Produktname">
```

Next line

```
<input type="text" name="pro_name_1"  id="pro_name_1"  placeholder="Produktname">
```

and so on. After that the data have to be send in POST request to PHP file.

The PHP file read them all and put them in array for usage later.

The PHP code:

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/action/conn/dbc.php';


$fields = array();
$counter = $_POST['counter'];
if ($counter > 0) {
  for ($i=0; $i <= $counter; $i++) {
      $proName   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pro_name_'.$i]);
      echo $proName.'<b/r>';
      $proAmount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pro_count_'.$i]);
      echo $proAmount.'<b/r>';
      $proPrice  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pro_price_'.$i]);
      echo $proPrice.'<b/r>';
  }
}
```

The problem is some of those field having the value NULL even if the wasn't NULL. I believe that the loop is too fast for that. I'm asking for suggestions for this problem and for a solution.

The HTML:

```
<form action="run.php" method="post">
    <input id="counter" name="counter" type="number" hidden value="0">
    <table id="VerkaufTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Vers.: 0</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro_name_0"  id="pro_name_0"  placeholder="Produktname"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro_count_0" id="pro_count_0" placeholder="Produktmenge"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro_price_0" id="pro_price_0" placeholder="Produktpreis"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

The counter does the count of the fields so php can knows the counts.

I thought about sending POST request with the data in jQuery so I don't have to do this array. But I'm not that good with jQuery so it's a preferred way for me for now.

Looking forwards :)

**UPDATE**: this what I see in the `var_dump($_POST)`

```
array(11) {
 ["counter"]=> string(1) "2"
 ["pro_name_0"]=> string(5) "Ortel"
 ["pro_count_0"]=> string(1) "1"
 ["pro_price_0"]=> string(2) "20"
//  Second line
 ["pro_name_1_"]=> string(7) "Samsung"
 ["pro_count_1"]=> string(1) "2"
 ["pro_price_1"]=> string(2) "10"
// Third line
 ["pro_name_2_"]=> string(10) "Headphones"
 ["pro_count_2"]=> string(1) "1"
 ["pro_price_2"]=> string(2) "20"
 ["submit"]=> string(0) ""
}

// This is from the ones inside the loop
Notice: Undefined index: pro_name_1 in E:\Hosted\testField\run.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: pro_name_2 in E:\Hosted\testField\run.php on line 10
```

Comment: I doubt the issue is that the loop is too fast to be reading the POST values - accessing array values doesn't work like that. What do you see with `var_dump($_POST);` outside of the loop? Unrelated, `<b/r>` isn't an HTML tag, you're looking for `<br />`. I don't see anything glaring with your inputs or the names of them.

Comment: The `_POST` data is in a fixed array so a for loop can't be too fast

Comment: Try to print all the post data as soon as you enter run.php to see if everything is correct in the post array

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones the <b/r> was by mistake. i dont know how they got there... i will post what i see in the `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Your dump for index 1 shows pro_name_1_, not pro_name_1. Same for 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a counter at all, as you can reformat your FORM to use grouped inputs like so:

```
<form action="run.php" method="post">
    <table id="VerkaufTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Vers.: 0</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro[0][name]"  id="pro_name_0"  placeholder="Produktname"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro[0][count]" id="pro_count_0" placeholder="Produktmenge"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro[0][price]" id="pro_price_0" placeholder="Produktpreis"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

and you can adjust JS upon adding a field to add it shifting the id of `0` to `1` and so on:

```
            <td><input type="text" name="pro[1][name]"  id="pro_name_0"  placeholder="Produktname"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro[1][count]" id="pro_count_0" placeholder="Produktmenge"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pro[1][price]" id="pro_price_0" placeholder="Produktpreis"></td>
```

This will then output the POST like:

```
pro = [
    [
        'name' => 'Ortel',
        'count' => '1',
        'price' => '20'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Samsung',
        'count' => '2',
        'price' => '10'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Headphones',
        'count' => '1',
        'price' => '20'
    ]
]
```

and you will be able to work with the `$_POST` output much easier

#### Edit

And since you asked about Mysql, it should work similarly to what you posted with few diffs:

```
if (!empty($pro)) {
  foreach ($pro as $p) {
      $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $p['name']);
      $count = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $p['count']);
      $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $p['price']);

      // do your mysql query here...

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man. that was what im expecting. you have any idea how to pass them into `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and store the "passed" ones?

Comment: Thank you man. i appreciate that a lot. my array looks like `$_POST['pro'][0]["name"]`. is that gonna work?

Comment: @AssadRajab Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You must use prepared statements and parameterize your data.

Comment: @Dharman yeah i know. it was faster to write the code here. im still using the example you gave me last time.